# Improve this recursive search with Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to improve a part of my code by using Regex rather than regular replace, to get clean string to submit to a Solr's client.

```
String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
        var replaceString = this;
        for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
            replaceString = replaceString.replace(find[i], replace[i]);
        }
        return replaceString;
    };

var match = [
                    '\\',
                    '+',
                    '-',
                    '&',
                    '|',
                    '!',
                    '(',
                    ')',
                    '{',
                    '}',
                    '[',
                    ']',
                    '^',
                    '~',
                    '*',
                    '?',
                    ':',
                    '"',
                    ';',
                    ' '
                ];        
                var replace = [
                    '\\\\',
                    '\\+',
                    '\\-',
                    '\\&',
                    '\\|',
                    '\\!',
                    '\\(',
                    '\\)',
                    '\\{',
                    '\\}',
                    '\\[',
                    '\\]',
                    '\\^',
                    '\\~',
                    '\\*',
                    '\\?',
                    '\\:',
                    '\\"',
                    '\\;',
                    '\\ '
                ];                    
                _.map(object, function (field) {
                    field.replaceArray(match, replace);
                });
```

Could exists a way to use a Regex instead ?

I tried to replace

```
field.replaceArray(match, replace);
```

to this

```
field.replace(/([\\+-&|!(){}[]^~*?:";])/g, '\\$1');
```

but it doesn't work probably because I don't understand enough how Regex works :(

Comment: Where is the recursion here..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the square brackets. Also put the hyphen at the end because in second place it indicates a range:

```
field.replace(/([\\+&|!(){}\[\]^~*?:"; -])/g, '\\$1');
```

[regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/qA3mT4/1)

Comment: thanks a lot, and this regex tester is really great one!